# How to update variable above @NgModule in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to send data from other file and store inside the value of variable **configuration** declared above @NgModule. Since it is outside of class AppModule {} then how I can update it.

```
import { Inject, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';



**let configuration = " ";**

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import { Inject, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';



**window["someVariable"] = "";**

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can access this later like this:

- window["someVariable"];

You can set value like this:

- window["someVariable"] = "blabla";